# Why can readonly fields be modified through ref parameters?

Tags: c#, .net, ref

Consider:

```
class Foo
{
    private readonly string _value;

    public Foo()
    {
        Bar(ref _value);
    }

    private void Bar(ref string value)
    {
        value = "hello world";
    }

    public string Value
    {
        get { return _value; }
    }
}

// ...

var foo = new Foo();
Console.WriteLine(foo.Value); // "hello world"
```

How does this  even compile, nonetheless work?  I should not be able to assign a the different value to `_value` field outside of the constructor, as it's marked with `readonly`.  However, pass it by `ref` to a method, and it can indeed be manipulated.

Is this dangerous?  Why?  It feels wrong to me, but I can't quite put my finger on it.

Comment: Because a readonly value that can never be written already exists, it is `default`.  A useful `readonly` variable *must* be written at least once.  The not-so-obvious detail is that field initialization actually happens in the constructor, the C# compiler moves the code.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It compiles because you're only passing the value as a `ref` parameter in the constructor (where `readonly` fields are allowed to be set). If you moved your call to `Bar()` into some other method, it would fail.

```
class Foo
{
    private readonly string _value;

    public Foo()
    {
        Bar(ref _value);
    }

    public void Baz()
    {
        Bar(ref _value);
    }

    private void Bar(ref string value)
    {
        value = "hello world";
    }

    public string Value
    {
        get { return _value; }
    }
}
```

The above code provides a very telling compiler error:

> A readonly field cannot be passed ref or out (except in a constructor)

Comment: pretty much. not dangerous because _value cannot be modified after construction nor is it exposed externally (aside from your get accessor)

Comment: Thanks.  Somehow that slipped by me. :)