# Why can't I ref return a static readonly field?

Tags: c#, return, ref, c#-7.0

The following code doesn't compile with `C# 7.0` / Visual Studio 2017.2:

```
class C {
    private static readonly int s = 5;
    public static ref int Data => ref s;
}
```

Is there an technical reason for disallowing references on static readonly fields or is this just a missing feature?

The error message says:

> CS8162: A static readonly field cannot returned by reference.

Comment: [Found a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34552287/why-can-readonly-fields-be-modified-through-ref-parameters).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because it's `readonly`.

The point of `ref` is to allow the referenced variable to be changed, which would violate `readonly`.

Comment: Ok, missunderstanding on my side. I Thought the point of `ref` is to prevent copying value types (structs).

Comment: @ventiseis: That's the other purpose of `ref`.  But since there is no `ref readonly`, you can't separate the two purposes.

Answer (score 4):

This is now possible in C# 7.2.

```
class C {
    private static readonly int s = 5;
    public static ref readonly int Data => ref s;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't *yet* return a reference to a readonly field, as ref returns are mutable. However, the `ref readonly` feature is planned for a future version of C# ([currently pencilled in for C# 7.2, but that may change](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/38)).

This feature will likely address both the ability to return references to readonly fields, as well as allowing `ref` parameters to be marked as readonly too, to offer the guarantee that the values referenced won't be modified by the method.